# Inequality $(\ln(n)-\frac{1+2\beta-2s}{s}\ln(\ln(n)))^{\frac{1-\overline{s}}{\underline{s}}}\le O(1)(\ln(n))^{\frac{1-\overline{s}}{\underline{s}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

I have given $\beta>0$ and $0<\underline s\le s\le\overline s\le 2$. I want to proof for $n\to\infty$ that
$$\left(\log(n)-\frac{1+2\beta-2s}{s}\log(\log(n))\right)^{\frac{1-\overline{s}}{\underline{s}}}
    \le O(1)(\log(n))^{\frac{1-\overline{s}}{\underline{s}}}.$$
Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log(\log(n))=\infty$ I'm not sure why this should be true.

> **Context:** I want to proof that $$O(\hat h_n^{\bar s-1}\exp(1/\hat h_n^{\bar s}))\le O(1)(\log n)^{(1-\bar{s}) / \underline{s}}
>  \exp\{(\log n)^{\bar{s} / s}\}$$ where $\hat{h}_n =\left(\frac{\log
>  n}{2}-\frac{\bar{\beta}-s+1 / 2}{s} \log \log
>  n\right)^{-1 / s}$. Inserting this yields \begin{align} \hat
>  h_n^{\overline{s}-1}\exp({1/\hat
>  h_n^{\overline{s}}})&=\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{\log(n)}{2}-\frac{\beta-s+\frac{1}{2}}{s}\log(\log(n))\right)^{\frac{1-\overline{s}}{\overline{s}}}\log(n)^{\frac{\overline{s}-\beta-\frac{1}{2}}{\overline{s}}}\\
>      &\le\sqrt{2}\left(\log(n)-\frac{2\beta+1-2s}{s}\log(\log(n))\right)^{\frac{1-\overline{s}}{\underline{s}}}\log(n)^{\overline{s}/s}\\
>      &\overset{!}{\le} O(1)(\log(n))^{\frac{1-\overline{s}}{\underline{s}}}\exp
>  \left\{\log(n)^{\overline{s}/s}\right\} \end{align} For the rear term
> one can simply use $x<\exp(x)$.

Comment: Is the constant $O(1)$ supposed to be independent of the parameters?

Comment: Note that your problem is equivalent to $$cx\leq x-\frac{1+2\beta-s}{s}\ln(x) \leq Cx.$$ If $c,C$ are allowed to depend on $s,\beta$, then this is rather trivial.